# Why does linux use two GOT sections in x64? .GOT vs .got.plt

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, elf, got

I'm trying to figure out the difference between these two sections, this may appear to be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676472/what-is-the-difference-between-got-and-got-plt-section), but the answer given there didn't explain a lot, so I'd like a more detailed and concise explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The split is due to security reasons. By default (used to be only under `-Wl,-z,relro` in the past) `.got` section is remapped as read-only once dynamic loader resolved all data relocations at startup (i.e. before entering `main` function) to prevent [some types of exploits](https://systemoverlord.com/2017/03/19/got-and-plt-for-pwning.html). `.got.plt` can not be remapped because of [lazy symbol binding](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.prog%2Ftopic%2Fdevel_Lazy_binding.html) (unless `LD_BIND_NOW` or `-Wl,-z,now` were used in which case lazy binding is turned off and `.got.plt` is remapped as well).